# Installing package for different versions of Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, easy-install

I have in my laptop installed both python 2.7 and python 3.5 . When I install a package and use for example:

```
pip install thunder-python
```

or

```
easy_install thunder
```

in command prompt the packages are installed for python 3.5. How can I install the packages in order to use them in python 2.7? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Go to the installation path of Python 2.7; locate pip and add it it the PATH variable, before 3.5's path

Comment: That means that every time I have to make this change? I mean if I want to use python 3.5 I have to change again the order yea?

Comment: Yes. That is the only possible way I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your `PATH` in system settings, and you will be able to run:

`pip3 thunder` to install packages for Python 3.x

and

`pip2 thunder` or `pip2.7 thunder` to install packages for Python 2.7.

Without modifying `PATH`, for Python 2.7 you can run the command directly:

`C:\Python27\Scripts\pip thunder`.

After modifying the `PATH` `pip` command will be called from the directory found first, so if you add Python2.7 directory to the end you'll get `pip` to run for Python3, if you add Python2.7 to the start, you'll get `pip` to run for Python2.7.

Answer (score -1):

How about using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)?
If you use it, you can change and switch version and install package like this.

```
$ pyenv local 2.7.X
$ pip install thunder-python
```

after that

```
$ pyenv local 3.5.X
$ pip install thunder-python
```