# How to set default python version for pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

OS: Mac OS X 10.11.3

I have Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.4.3.

When I `pip install some_package` pip installs package for Python 2.7.10, but I want to install package for Python 3.4.3.

How I can set default Python or install package for 3.4.3?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808902/installing-package-in-python

Answer (score 7):

Much like the `python`/`python3` executables, `pip` also has two variants. You can use `pip3` to install Python 3 packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can install pip package using virtual environment:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3env
source py3env/bin/activate
pip install package-name
```